# Cat behaving strangely

Tags: cats

My cat is starting to act strange sometimes. His eyes will get large, and he'll start meowing loudly and trying to bite at me, if I try to touch him he just meows louder. I usually just let my arm go limp when we'd play and he'd get nippy, but now if I do he latches on and starts to pull like he wants to drag me somewhere. This comes and goes in spells, I thought he might be hurt somewhere and thats why he was avoiding touch but when he's not in a mood and I pet him he's fine. He's only 3 so I don't think he has brain problems. And he's fixed too so I really don't know whats going on.

Comment: Any case of a change in behavior should always result in a visit to your vet.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that he is neutered and doing this! On that note, I think males are a little more crazy than females.

Our cat gets like this too. I usually refer to him as amped or being a spaz. He goes totally crazy. He gets huge eyes like he is on the hunt. He will pounce on everything. He loves to run and bite my feet and legs. If I’m sitting, he will bite my hands and arms. His back fur will twitch, and he will crouch to the ground. He may also run from room to room, jump on furniture, and attack marks on the wall.

I would just find ways to calm the cat down. Don’t know if these work at all, but I’ve seen online that there is aroma therapy for pets or cbd oil for pets. What I normally do is throw him under a blanket. Don’t know why, but maybe the weight of the blanket or the darkness or something soothes him and gets him to calm down.

To stop him from biting me, I try to avoid it. I pick him up (even if he doesn’t want it) and move him to a different spot or room. I will also close doors to separate us.

Another thing I do is go and get toys and play rough with him. I have a feather wand and just whip it all over the place and it helps get his energy out. Or, I will chuck balls throughout the house and let him go chase them.

Lastly, maybe you could train him? I know people recommend positive reinforcement (via treats). This wasn’t good enough for our cat, so we use a spray bottle and say down. He is pretty responsive to that.

Since our cat got neutered last week, the amount of these “amped up” episodes has drastically gone down!

Good luck!